# IntelliJ Plugin Development: How to preview the plugin.xml result?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, preview, intellij-plugin

I am developing an IntelliJ plugin and want to upload it into the IntelliJ Plugin Repository. But I want to be on the save side and would like to get a preview of the resulting description text. Especially I would like to see the arrangement of Lists, Links and Images.

It looks like IntelliJ doesn't provide such. So do I really have to upload, check, modify, reupload?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a .zip and add it manually into my IDE worked fine. There I see resulting layout of my own plugin description.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Yep. That's a solution! Thanks! Next issue is that the Plugin Repository Webinterface drops most of the html tags so it gets hard to keep everything consistent.